# Golang container/list creating a FindAll function

Tags: go

I was wondering if this is the way to create and pass 'generic'(yeah I know, a sensitive word in GoLang) lists to a FindAll function.

Here's my attempt:

```
package main

import (
    "container/list"
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func FindAll(lst *list.List, p func(interface{}) bool) *list.List {
    ans := list.New()

    for i := lst.Front(); i != nil; i = i.Next() {
        if p(i.Value) {
            ans.PushBack(i.Value)
        }
    }
    return ans
}

func ConvertToInt(p func(int) bool) func(interface{}) bool {
    return func(v interface{}) bool {
        if value, ok := v.(int); ok {
            if p(value) {
                return true
            } else {
                return false
            }
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }
}

func IsEven(n int) bool {
    if n%2 == 0 {
        return true
    }
    return false
}

func ConvertoString(p func(s string) bool) func(interface{}) bool {
    return func(v interface{}) bool {
        if value, ok := v.(string); ok {
            if p(value) {
                return true
            } else {
                return false
            }
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }
}

func IsHello(str string) bool {
    if strings.ToLower(str) == "hello" {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Find All Programs!\n\n")

    lsti := list.New()

    for i := 0; i < 11; i++ {
        lsti.PushBack(i)
    }

    ansIsEven := FindAll(lsti, ConvertToInt(IsEven))

    for i := ansIsEven.Front(); i != nil; i = i.Next() {
        if value, ok := i.Value.(int); ok {
            fmt.Printf("Found even: %d\n", value)
        } else {
            fmt.Println("Huh! What's that?")
        }
    }

}
```

I've been playing with this for a while and thought I'd better get the advice of the Go experts before I convince myself its correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code as-is is pretty fine, but you should ask your self 2 questions:

1. Why shouldn't you use a typed slice? (interface{} performance is slow compared to the explicit type, although it will greatly improve in Go 1.7)

2. Would it be better to implement your specific type as a linked list?

Something like [this](https://play.golang.org/p/jjZe7AAUFA) can be much more efficient:

```
type IntList []int

func (l IntList) Filter(fn func(v int) bool) IntList {
    var o IntList
    for _, v := range l {
        if fn(v) {
            o = append(o, v)
        }
    }
    return o
}
```

There's almost always a better alternative to `container/list`, however it all depends on your use case.

Comment: Yeah I know the performance data structure is the array with slices but I'm currently investigating what the language has to offer and how to navigate with those features. I'll be OK with "code as-is is pretty fine".